# Turing-reducibility for guaranteed decider

Tags: turing-machines, rice-theorem, decidability

The following exercise is taken from Theoretical Computer Science by Atiba.

> Use Rice's theorem to demonstrate that every decidable language is Turing reducible to some language that is already guaranteed to be decidable (for example, the language of strings that represent the primes).

My reasoning is the following. Assume that $L$ is a decidable language. Since $L$ is decidable, there exists a Turing machine $M$ that can decide whether a given string belongs to $L$ or not. Therefore, the language $L'$ defined by the set of all strings accepted by $M$ is either trivial or undecidable. If $L'$ is trivial, then it contains all or none of the strings in $L$, and thus $L$ is Turing reducible to $L$. In this case, we are done, because $L$ is Turing reducible to a trivial language, which is guaranteed to be decidable. We then repeat similar arguments until we reach a trivial language.

However, I am highly doubtful of this strategy, because except for simple toy examples, I cannot tell how many stages this argument should repeat for. I would really appreciate any demonstration of the statement above.

Comment: I can’t make any sense of what Rice’s theorem is supposed to do here. Trivially, every decidable language is Turing reducible to any language you want.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/156052/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4595177/14578, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/52254/5038.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, I thought so too. I think a more precise version of what the book is asking about is the following: given $D$ a fixed decidable language, show that any language $L$ is decidable iff $L \leq_T D$.